# An Awkward Integral Arising in Scattering of $\alpha$-Particle by Nucleus

Tags: integration

I wonder whether anyone knows how to do the integral

$$\int\frac{dr}{r\sqrt{r^2 -br\exp(-kr)-a^2}}  .$$

It arises when the Rutherford scattering problem is instisted upon being treated classically instead of by treating the incoming $\alpha$-Particle as a wave, as is done in the *Born* approximation. The *wave*-mechanical treatment *does* yield a solution in elementary functions, whence it *might seem* that this integral is tractable, and that one could perhaps *reverse-engineer* the answer to this question from that ... but then *not necessarily*, as that would only yield the value of the integral *at certain special end-points*, and not the actual *content* of it as a function of $r$.

Also the $b$ in this is not the same $b$ as in the non-Yukawa-ised form of this this problem & simply *brought over* from  it: rather $b$ will now be given by a *lambertw* function ... but that's not so very bad atall. Infact, it'll just be

$$\frac{w(kb_0)}{k} ,$$

with $b_0$ being the $b$ in the *non-Yukawa-ised* form. The closest approach of the α-particle being well within the shielding corresponds to $kb_0$ being a small fraction of 1, & therefore $b$ being not much less than $b_0$ ... $b≈b_0(1-kb_0(1-\frac{3}{2}kb_0(1-\frac{16}{9}kb_0)))$, infact.

Comment: is that $=$ sign a typo?

Comment: Oh yes! Certainly is! Thankyou.

Comment: Is this related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2961323/asymptotic-behavior-of-the-coulomb-logarithm)?

Comment: I can see that that one 8

Comment: is _similar_, & also arises in a _Yukawa potential_ -type problem. _That_ question is not mine, however; and the integral is somewhat different _in detail_, having _u __in the denominator___ in the argument of the exponential, and ___no__ u_ in the denominator outside the square-root.

Comment: @AmbretteOrrisey The integral in that question is actually the $a$-derivative of your integral now that I look at it (with suitable parameter redefinition), assuming the bounds of your integral are $(r^*,\infty)$, where $r^*$ is the turning point.

Comment: ¶ The question _of mine_ that this arises from is the _normalisation of Rutherford differential cross-section_ (not verbatim name) problem that I posted a few days ago. ¶ One of the keys on my virtual keypad acts as a _post_ button: I wish it wouldn't, as I keep accidentally sending fragments of comments!

Comment: @That's the one! the relation a (impact parameter)  =(b/2)cot(φ/2) is obtained by substituing r=∞ & r=b into the _non_ -'Yukawa-ised' form of this, which _is_ tractable.

Comment: I made another typo - a much more important one ... I've fixed it now!

Comment: @AmbretteOrrisey OK now it is equivalent to the one inside the cosine in the other question (substitute r->a/u). Admittedly not super helpful since neither seems to have an elementary antiderivative.

Comment: Is it!? Right so the matter of the variable being _reciprocated_ in the argument of the ewponential to the other is not a big obstacle, and they teanspire to be the same!  Thankyou for that observation. That's good then, because it mezns

Comment: or _tends_to mean that this integral has some degree of _ubiquiosity_ in Yukawa-pitential-type setups, & therefore ought at least to be somewhat studied. You might even _define __a new function___ as being the solution of it. That's effectively all that's meant, often, when you say that an integral _is_ tractable. It just means you've accepted the integral _of it_ amongst the _canon_ of _functions_. That's 'kind of' what it is with _elliptic_ functions ... but admittedly they have so very _vast_ scope of interconnections with other functions, we _cannot but_, really, call them _bona fide_ func